# How to use associative arrays or Hash tables in Chicken Scheme?

Tags: hashmap, scheme, hashtable, chicken-scheme

**How to use associative arrays or Hash tables in Chicken Scheme?**

I'm looking for a data structure that supports (near) O(1) access to data based on keys, which should work like Java's `HashMap` or Python's `dict` data structures in Chicken Scheme.
There seem to be eggs that implement that functionality, but I'd rather use something more standard.

Apparently, there seems to be an effort to define a standard library with Scheme R6RS, but I'm not sure if that's a viable option for Chicken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chicken Scheme supports efficient hash tables natively by implementing [SRFI-69](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-69/srfi-69.html) and [SRFI-90](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-90/srfi-90.html), take a look at the [documentation](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Unit%20srfi-69#hash-table-procedures). It also supports association lists, but that's just a convention for structuring and searching normal lists of pairs, and they're not meant to allow efficient searches.